# Optimization algorithm for calculating multiplier and divisor values

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, optimization

I'm trying to optimize an algorithm and I can't think of a better way to do it.

There is one input (a clock frequency value) that will go through a combination of multipliers and divisors.

- The goal is to find the set of multiplier and divisor values that will produce the desired output value, given the input.

> OutClk = (InClk * Mult1 * Mult2 * Mult3 * Mult4 / Div1 ) / Div2

My current (naive?) implementation is:

```
#define PRE_MIN 10000000
#define PRE_MAX 20000000

// Available values of the multipliers and divisors.
uint8_t mult1_vals[] = {1, 2};
uint8_t mult2_vals[] = {1, 2, 4, 8};
uint8_t mult3_vals[] = {3, 5, 7};
uint8_t div1_vals[] = {1, 2, 4};
uint8_t div2_vals[] = {1, 2, 4, 8};

bool exists_mults_divs(uint32_t in_val, uint32_t out_val)
{
    uint8_t i_m1, i_m2, i_m3, i_d1, i_d2;
    uint32_t calc_val;

    for (i_m1 = 0; i_m1 < sizeof(mult1_vals); i_m1++) {
    for (i_m2 = 0; i_m2 < sizeof(mult2_vals); i_m2++) {
    for (i_m3 = 0; i_m3 < sizeof(mult3_vals); i_m3++) {
    for (i_div1 = 0; i_div1 < sizeof(div1_vals); i_div1++) {

    calc_val = in_val * (mult1_vals[i_m1] * mult2_vals[i_m2] *
                         mult3_vals[i_m3] / div1_vals[i_div1]);
    if ((calc_val <= PRE_MIN) || (calc_val > PRE_MAX))
        continue; // Can this be refactored?

    for (i_div2 = 0; i_div2 < sizeof(div2_vals); i_div2++) {
        calc_val /= div2_vals[i_div2];
        if (calc_val == out_val)
            return true;
    }

    }
    }
    }
    }

    // No multiplier/divisor values found to produce the desired out_val.
    return false;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize this? Or use some algorithmic approach?

I'm using C, but any type of pseudo code is OK with me.

**EDIT:**
Some examples for clarification. This will return `true`:

```
exists_mults_divs(2000000, 7000000); // in=2000000, out=7000000
// Iterating over the values internally:
// 1. in * 1 * 1 * 3 / 1 = 6000000
//    6000000 is not within PRE_MIN/MAX range of 10-20000000.
// 2. in * 1 * 1 * 5 / 1 = 10000000 is within range, try varying div2
//    2a. div2=1 => 10000000 / 1 = 10000000 != 7000000 not desired out
//    2b. div2=2 => 10000000 / 2 = 50000000 != 7000000
//    etc.
// 3. in * 1 * 1 * 7 / 1 = 7000000 not within range
// etc.
// 4. in * 1 * 2 * 7 / 1 = 14000000 is within range, try varying div2
//    4a. div2=1 => 14000000 / 1 != 7000000
//    4b. div2=2 => 14000000 / 2 == 7000000 IS desired out
//
// RETURN RESULT:
//    TRUE since a 2000000 in can generate a 7000000 out with
//    mult1=1, mult2=2, mult3=7, div1=1, div2=2
```

This will return `false`:

```
exists_mults_divs(2000000, 999999999);
```

Because there is no combination of divisor and multiplier with the available values that will result in getting the `999999999`.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of desired input and output? Why is that particular number of multipliers and divisors significant? Five nested for loops seems pretty brute force, but a more detailed problem specification would help in identifying if there is a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks to compare to? Some compiler switches may do a heck of a let better optimizations than one could do by hand

Comment: @paisanco The desired multipliers and divisors are physical electronic components with physical limitations. I agree that this is pretty brute force, that's why I'm seeking help since I can't figure this out.

Comment: @Alejandro No benchmarks. Allowing the compiler to do it's thing may be a pragmatic approach but I'd still enjoy seeing some optimized solutions to this.

Comment: @user2162449 I agree, seeing some optimizations to this would be beneficial, but you  can learn a great amount by also studying the resulting assembly =)

Comment: Your description says `Mult4 / Div1`, but I don't see any mention of a fourth multiplier in your code, and the code divides `Mult3` by `Div1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering the formula, we have

```
OutClk/(Mult1*Mult2*Mult3) = InClk/(Div1*Div2);
```

- Take a look at the `Mult1 = {1, 2}` and `Mult2 = {1, 2, 4, 8}`, notice that, they are all power of two.
- Similarly, with `Div1` and `Div2`, they also power of two.
- `Mult3  = {3,5,7}` , which are all prime numbers.

So, what we need to do is divide both InClk and OutClk by their greatest common divider (GCD)

```
int g = gcd(InClk, OutClk);

InClk /= g;

OutClk/= g;
```

In order for `InClk == OutClk`, we need to make both `InClk/g` and `OutClk/g` equal to 1.

And what is left in InClk after the division, we try to divide it by the largest element in each `div_vals` that InClk can be divided. (Because each element in `div_vals` all are power of two, so we need to pick the largest).

```
for(int i = sizeof(div1_vals) - 1; i>= 0; i--)
    if(InClk % div1_vals[i] == 0){
        InClk/= div1_vals[i];
        break;
    }

for(int i = sizeof(div2_vals) - 1; i>= 0; i--)
    if(InClk % div2_vals[i] == 0){
        InClk/= div2_vals[i];
        break;
    }
```

Similarly for `OutClk`

```
for(int i = sizeof(mul1_vals) - 1; i>= 0; i--)
    if(OutClk % mul1_vals[i] == 0){
        OutClk/= mul1_vals[i];
        break;
    }
....
```

In the end, if `InClk == 1 and OutClk == 1`, we return true, else false.

Time complexity is ***O(n)*** with n is maximum number of elements in all mul1_vals, ...